# In Angular my app is not updated, only appears 'app is running'

Tags: angular

I'm making an app with a component (Dado is the component's name), but the content of the component is not seen in the browser, only appears "app is running". Where could the fault be?

These are the Appcomponent files:

app.module.ts:

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform- 
 browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { DadoComponent } from './dado/dado.component';


 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  DadoComponent
  ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
 <div style="text-align:center">
 <app-dado></app-dado>
 <app-dado></app-dado>
 <app-dado></app-dado>  
 </div>
```

And these are the Dadocomponent files:

dado.component.ts:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-dado',
  templateUrl: './dado.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dado.component.css']
 })

 export class DadoComponent implements OnInit {
  valor: number;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.valor = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  }

 }
```

dado.component.html:

```
  <div class="forma">
   {{valor}}
  </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: any console errors so far?

Comment: You probably forgot to save files, or are executing the wrong app: nothing in the code you posted contains "app is running".

Comment: I save files with the updates. 'app is running' is the message of Angular.

Comment: did you open your browser with the address: localhost:4200? Where is the "app is running" message from Angular? In the terminal window?

Comment: No, it is in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1zg5ar) of your code. There might be some spacing issues that are preventing the output or it can be because of the spacing here -

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-
 browser';
```

I didn't have to change anything in your code other than the spacing issues.